# Properties of the Jordan basis of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, jordan-algebras

Suppose $A$ is a square matrix $d\times d$ and that it's a linear opetaror over the albgeraicly closed field $\mathbb{C}$. In particular, $A$ has $n$ different eigen values, each one with multiplicity $m_i$. Therefore $A$ is similar to a Jordan matrix in a basis $\mathcal{J}:=(w_{i,j}; i=1, ... , n, j=1, ..., m_i)$ formed by the generalized eigen vectors of $A$. Now, why would the next statement be true?

$$A w_{i,j}=\lambda_i w_{i,j} + w_{i,j+1} \text{ where } w_{i,m_i+1}=0.$$

I think that the convention $w_{i,m_i+1}=0$ is because since $A$ is a Jordan form, it's block diagonal with $\lambda_i, \; i=1,..., n$ in its diagonal and 1's over them except for the rows where we change eigen value. Also, by thinking of $A$ as a Jordan form, and multiplying it for a vector $[v]_{J}=(v_1, v_2, ... , v_d)^T$ written in de $\mathcal{J}$ base, I can see how
\begin{align}
Av = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1 v_1 + v_2\\
\vdots\\
\lambda_1 v_{m_1} + 0 v_{m_1+1}\\
\lambda_2 v_{m_1+1} + v_{m_1+2}\\
\vdots 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
So, my intuition is that to calculate the $k-th$ row, you multiply the $k-th$ entry on your vector $v$ by the asociated eigen value $\lambda$ and then add it with the next entry. However I'm having trouble seeing why this, in the case of the vectors of the base, would be as if the $k-th$ row of $w_{i,j}$ is precisely $w_{i,j}$ and then the next one is that of $w_{i,j+1}$, which in principle should be a different vector altogether. I also tried thinking $w_{i,j}$ as $0's$ and a $1$ in the $k-th$ row... however with that I get that it should be $A w_{i,j}=-\lambda_i w_{i,j} + w_{i,j-1}$ instead.

Any guidance in the right direction is highly appreciated. As well as any reference where I can find more about the Jordan form and its properties.

Comment: Do your Jordan matrices have ones below or above the diagonal? Your equation for $Aw_{i,j}$ suggests ones below the diagonal while your equation for $Av$ (which probably should be $[A]_{\mathcal J} [v]_{\mathcal J}$ instead) suggests ones above the diagonal. How are the $w_{i,j}$ ordered in $\mathcal J$?

Comment: Actually, where I got the reference they didn't specify. Is there a definition of Jordan matrix with ones under de diagonal?

Comment: There are different conventions. In order for the matrix to be defined you have to specify the order of the basis vectors, so that should have happened. Can you give us a reference to the text you are using?

Comment: Sure, this is the link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.09207. I am following the proof of the Lemma B.1.

Comment: Looks like that never actually uses the Jordan matrix, just the basis vectors, which then don't need to be ordered. If you want the matrix to have ones above the diagonal, you need $\mathcal J$ to be ordered this way: $\mathcal J = (w_{1,m_1}, w_{1,m_1-1}, \dots, w_{1,1}, w_{2,m_2}, w_{2,m_2-1}, \dots, w_{2,1}, \dots)$. So for each $i$ you list the basis vectors $w_{i,j}$ such that $j$ is *decreasing*.